# PARALLEL (AUTO) Oracle Hint and PARALLEL_MIN_TIME_THRESHOLD

Tags: sql, oracle, parallel-processing, hint, parallel-execution

The Oracle hint `PARALLEL (AUTO)` seems to be preventing parallel execution.  The following is on a 12c development server, but we have seen similar behavior on a 19c server.  `PARALLEL` yields parallel execution, but `PARALLEL (AUTO)` does not.  Why not?

```sql
drop table ParallelAuto;

create table ParallelAuto as
  select level id from dual connect by level <= 1
;

select pdml_enabled, pdml_status, pddl_status, pq_status 
  from v$session 
  where sid = (select sid from v$mystat where rownum = 1)
;
```

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| PDML_ENABLED | PDML_STATUS | PDDL_STATUS | PQ_STATUS |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| NO           | DISABLED    | ENABLED     | ENABLED   |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

```sql
alter session ENABLE PARALLEL DML; 

select pdml_enabled, pdml_status, pddl_status, pq_status 
  from v$session 
  where sid = (select sid from v$mystat where rownum = 1)
;
```

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| PDML_ENABLED | PDML_STATUS | PDDL_STATUS | PQ_STATUS |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+ 
| YES          | ENABLED     | ENABLED     | ENABLED   |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

PDML is enabled.

The following are `%parallel%` parameters for reference.

```sql
select name, value, isdefault, ismodified, isadjusted 
  from v$parameter 
  where name like '%parallel%'  
;
```

```
+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
| NAME                            | VALUE  | ISDEFAULT | ISMODIFIED | ISADJUSTED |
+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
| parallel_server                 | FALSE  | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_server_instances       | 1      | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| recovery_parallelism            | 0      | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| fast_start_parallel_rollback    | LOW    | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_min_percent            | 0      | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_min_servers            | 32     | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_max_servers            | 320    | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_instance_group         |        | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_execution_message_size | 16384  | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_degree_policy          | MANUAL | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_adaptive_multi_user    | TRUE   | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_threads_per_cpu        | 2      | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_automatic_tuning       | FALSE  | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_io_cap_enabled         | FALSE  | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_min_time_threshold     | AUTO   | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_degree_limit           | CPU    | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_force_local            | FALSE  | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_servers_target         | 128    | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
| parallel_degree_level           | 100    | TRUE      | FALSE      | FALSE      |
+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Explaining this `UPDATE` DML shows we do indeed get a parallel execution.

```sql
update /*+ ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML PARALLEL */ ParallelAuto set id = 2;
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT      |              |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR       |              |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM) | :TQ10000     |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    UPDATE             | PARALLELAUTO |       |       |            |          |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     PX BLOCK ITERATOR |              |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| PARALLELAUTO |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
Note
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 2
```

However, when using the `PARALLEL (AUTO)` hint we no longer receive the parallel execution.

```sql
update /*+ ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML PARALLEL (AUTO) */ ParallelAuto set id = 3;
```

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT   |              |     1 |    13 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE            | PARALLELAUTO |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| PARALLELAUTO |     1 |    13 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
Note
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 1 because of parallel threshold
   - PDML disabled because object is not decorated with parallel clause
```

Just to confirm it is not the `PARALLEL_DEGREE_POLICY` let's change it to not be `MANUAL`.

```sql
alter session set parallel_degree_policy = AUTO;

select name, value, isdefault, ismodified, isadjusted
  from v$parameter
  where name like 'parallel_degree_policy'
;
```

```
+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
| NAME                            | VALUE  | ISDEFAULT | ISMODIFIED | ISADJUSTED |
+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
| parallel_degree_policy          | AUTO   | TRUE      | MODIFIED   | FALSE      |
+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

```sql
update /*+ ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML PARALLEL */ ParallelAuto set id = 3;
```

```
Note
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 2
```

```sql
update /*+ ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML PARALLEL (AUTO) */ ParallelAuto set id = 3;
```

```
Note
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 1 because of parallel threshold
   - PDML disabled because object is not decorated with parallel clause
```

Same results.

Even when we remove the PDML aspect from the statement, a surprising result is occurring for `SELECT` (Parallel Query - PQ) as well.

```sql
select /*+ PARALLEL */ * from ParallelAuto;
```

```
Note
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 2
```

```sql
select /*+ PARALLEL (AUTO) */ * from ParallelAuto;
```

```
Note
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 1 because of parallel threshold
```

There is very limited activity on this non-production server.

This behavior of `PARALLEL (AUTO)` seems to contradict the documentation (referenced below).

Oracle SQL Database Reference | PARALLEL_DEGREE_POLICY

> Note:Automatic degree of parallelism will be enabled regardless of the value of PARALLEL_DEGREE_POLICY if a PARALLEL hint is used at the SQL statement level.

Oracle SQL Reference Guide | Comments | Hints

> This hint overrides the value of the PARALLEL_DEGREE_POLICY initialization parameter. It applies to the SELECT, INSERT, MERGE, UPDATE, and DELETE portions of a statement, as well as to the table scan portion. If any parallel restrictions are violated, then the hint is ignored.

12c

> PARALLEL: The statement always is run parallel, and the database computes the degree of parallelism, which can be 2 or greater.
> PARALLEL (AUTO): The database computes the degree of parallelism, which can be 1 or greater. If the computed degree of parallelism is 1, then the statement runs serially.
> PARALLEL (MANUAL): The optimizer is forced to use the parallel settings of the objects in the statement.

19c/21c

> PARALLEL: The statement results in a degree of parallelism equal to or greater than the computed degree of parallelism, except when parallelism is not feasible for the lowest cost plan. When parallelism is is not feasible, the statement runs serially.
> PARALLEL (AUTO): The statement results in a degree of parallelism that is equal to or greater than the computed degree of parallelism, except when parallelism is not feasible for the lowest cost plan. When parallelism is is not feasible, the statement runs serially.
> PARALLEL (MANUAL): The optimizer is forced to use the parallel settings of the objects in the statement.

What is going on here?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PARALLEL(AUTO)` will not enable parallelism if the estimated run time is less than the `PARALLEL_MIN_TIME_THRESHOLD`, which defaults to 10 seconds (which is confusingly also called "AUTO"). This behavior is probably a good thing because parallelism adds a lot of overhead, and parallelism may unfairly use a huge amount of resources to make a fast statement only slightly faster.

You can test this behavior by creating a fake number of rows and making the optimizer think the SQL will take a long time:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.set_table_stats(user, 'PARALLELAUTO', numrows => 99999999999);
end;
/
```

Alternatively, you can modify `PARALLEL_MIN_TIME_THRESHOLD` at the session or system level. Although since your test table has only one row, there may not be any value low enough to trigger parallelism without also creating a fake row count.

```
alter session set parallel_min_time_threshold = 1;
```

Comment: In 12c the definition of ``/*+ PARALLEL */`` states it will "always" execute in parallel, but this definition changed in 19c so that now it matches ``/* PARALLEL (AUTO) */``.  In 12c, with only 1 record and parallel_min_time_threshold=1, and the ``/*+ PARALLEL */`` hint, it computed a degree of parallelism of 2 and still executed in parallel.  How would you get ``/*+ PARALLEL */`` to run serially?

Comment: I think the 12c documentation is incorrect, since there have always been some weird cases where parallelism doesn't work. `/*+ PARALLEL */` hints will run in serial for operations and features that don't support parallelism, such as an "INDEX SCAN UNIQUE" operation, or a select statement that uses a function without `PARALLEL_ENABLE` defined.